Mixed ANCOVA Assumptions
I have a Mixed ANCOVA. my within-subjects factor is Time [Pre- and post-intervention) and my between-subjects factor is Group [4 intervention]). My IVs are group and time. My DV is happiness, which is measured pre- and post-intervention. My Covariate is meaning in life measured once at baseline.
I have a question regarding assumption checks.
Question 1:
Regarding the assumption of the Homogeneity of Regression slopes, am I correct to believe this assumption is "The slope of the regression line between the CV and the DV should be the same for each level of IV"?
I am unsure how to assess this assumption for this model. Because my DV is measured twice, and time is an IV in my model, I am unsure how to assess this assumption for this model.
I see a few options and am not sure which is correct:

Test the interaction between Group and CV on pre-intervention DV scores
Test the interaction between Group and CV on post-intervention DV scores
Conduct the mixed ANCOVA, including the interaction term (Group x Time X CV)

Perhaps I should do all three?
Question 2:
Regarding the assumption of linearity, I am also confused for the same reason as the assumption above. I am not sure what aspect of the DV (pre, post or the change) is assumed to be linearly related to the CV for each level of the IV.
Question 3:
Regarding the assumption of Homogeneity of Variances:
To test this, would I assess the output of the main mixed ANCOVA and Levene's test?
Also, for this model, do I have to test the Homogeneity of covariance matrices?
Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer. I am struggling to find resources on how to test assumptions for my model or how many assumptions apply to my model. Any links to further resources would be greatly appreciated.

Check out the sections on checking assumptions of multiple regression at https://www.bookdown.org/rwnahhas/RMPH/mlr-linearity.html. ANCOVA is a kind of catch-all phrase for linear models with certain types of covariates. In the end it is an OLS regression, and those are the assumptions you need to worry about. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44928/ancova-and-its-disturbing-assumptions?rq=1

Q1) Homogeneity of Regression Slopes

Regarding the assumption of the Homogeneity of Regression slopes, am I correct to believe this assumption is "The slope of the regression line between the CV and the DV should be the same for each level of IV"?

Yes. This assumption states that the relationship between the covariate ("meaning in life", henceforth "MiL" and the dependent variable (happiness) should be consistent across the levels of the other independent variables (Group and Time).
Given that your model includes a within-subjects factor (Time) and a between-subjects factor (Group), you can:

Test the interaction between Group and MiL on pre-intervention DV scores: This approach tests whether the slope of MiL predicting pre-intervention happiness is consistent across different groups.

Test the interaction between Group and MiL on post-intervention DV scores: This tests whether the slope of MiL predicting post-intervention happiness is consistent across different groups.

Conduct the mixed ANCOVA, including the interaction term (Group x Time x MiL): This interaction tells you if the slopes for MiL vary across different combinations of Group and Time.


Q2) Linearity Assumption

Regarding the assumption of linearity, I am also confused for the same reason as the assumption above. I am not sure what aspect of the DV (pre, post or the change) is assumed to be linearly related to the CV for each level of the IV.

The linearity assumption in ANCOVA states that there should be a linear relationship between MiL and the dependent variable for each level of the independent variables:

Pre-intervention scores:
Check the linear association between MiL and pre-intervention happiness scores for each group.

Post-intervention scores:
Check the linear association between MiL and post-intervention happiness scores for each group.

Overall model:
In the mixed ANCOVA, ensure that the overall relationship between MiL and the dependent variable (considering all levels of Time and Group) is linear.


As for how to assess the linear associations, there are several approaches:

visual inspection of scatter plots of the data

Plotting MiL against happiness is an easy way to visually assess linearity. A nonlinear plot obviously indicates that the linearity assumption is violated.

Residual plots

Plotting the residuals from the model (typically on the Y axis) against MiL, and also against fitted values are also useful plots for assessing linearity. If the residuals display a random scatter around the horizontal axis, this suggests a linear relationship.

Statistical tests

A method that I like is to add nonlinear terms to the model to see if it improves the fit. These could be polynomial terms such as quadratic and cubic, or regression splines. Another approach is to use an additive model with a smooth term for MiL.
Q3) Homogeneity of Variances

Regarding the assumption of Homogeneity of Variances:
To test this, would I assess the output of the main mixed ANCOVA and Levene's test?
Also, for this model, do I have to test the Homogeneity of covariance matrices?

To test the assumption of homogeneity of variances you can use Levene's test on the pre-intervention and post-intervention happiness scores separately, which will test if the variances are equal across different groups.
You can also use Box's M test which tests whether the covariance matrices are equal across groups. Significant results indicate a violation of this assumption.
